# Can't access jQuery plugin variable inside callback in call parameters

Tags: jquery

I'm trying for the first time to create a jQuery plugin. Not something big or something that is not already out there, just want to feel the magic and get my hands dirty.

So the plugin it's about a notifier that show and hide on screen corners.

The structure is as follows:

```
;(function( $, window, document ) {
    "use strict"

    /**** some plugin methods ****/

    var callbackQueue = $({});
    $.callbackQueue = function(callback){
            callbackQueue.queue(function(next){
            callback();
            next();
        });
    };

    function easyNotifier( element, options ) {
        var defaults    = {
            /**** some default settings and style ****/
        },
        methods         = {
        beforeShow  :   undefined,
        afterShow   :   undefined,
        beforeClose :   undefined,
        afterClose  :   undefined,
        onClose     :   undefined,
    };

    /**** MpV.easyNotifier exist from the beginning ****/
    MpV.easyNotifier.methods = $.extend( {}, methods, { beforeShow : options.beforeShow, afterShow : options.afterShow, beforeClose : options.beforeClose, afterClose : options.afterClose, onCancel : options.onCancel });
    delete options.beforeShow && delete options.afterShow && delete options.beforeClose && delete options.afterClose && delete options.onClose;
    MpV.easyNotifier.params = $.extend( {}, defaults, options);

    this._version   = MpV.easyNotifier._version;
    this._name      = MpV.easyNotifier._name;
    this._author    = MpV.easyNotifier._author;

    /*
     *  Let's make some methods public.
     *
     */
    this.setMessage = MpM._setMessage;

    this.init();
    return this;
};

    easyNotifier.prototype.init = function() {
        $.each([MpV.easyNotifier.methods.beforeShow,MpM._construct],function(i,obj){
            $.callbackQueue(obj);
        });
    };

    $.easyNotifier = function(options){
        if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + MpV.easyNotifier._alias)) {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + MpV.easyNotifier._alias, new easyNotifier( this, options ));
        }
        //console.log($.data(this, 'plugin_' + MpV.easyNotifier._alias));
        return $.data(this, 'plugin_' + MpV.easyNotifier._alias);
    };
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

And here is the call:

```
var notifier = $.easyNotifier({
         position    :   ["bottom","right"],
         background  :   "rgba(60,118,141,.8)",
         title       :   "Some title",
         beforeShow  :   function(){
             console.log("beforeShow started");
             /* And here is the problem, the notifier variable is undefined */
             console.log(notifier);

             console.log("beforeShow ended");
         },
         afterClose  :   function(){
             /**** some fade out code here for another element ****/
         }
```

The console.log() just before the plugin return shows that everything is in place.

I tried to follow the code with some logging through the callbacks the the return.

So here is what i came to:

```
beforeShow started
undefined
beforeShow ended
construct started
construct ended
and then the console log just before the plugin return.
```

I think that for the variable to be not undefined the last line should be first. But i also think that the above flow is correct, the plugin can't return before the methods happen.

So what am i missing here? Why the notifier variable is undefined?
I am struggling for hours, so much that i think my approach is wrong.

Any help appreciated, and of course if you think that i've done something really bad with the structure please tell me.

Sorry for my bad English, thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `window.notifier` instead of just `notifier`.

Comment: @HarryBomrah, thanks for your raplay, just tryed what you suggested but window.notifier return the actual html code of notifier, i need the object where a store the public variables and methods.

Something like this:

object {
    _version:"0.1.04",
   /**** some more public paramters ****/
   setMessage : function(){}
   /**** that is the method im trying to access ****/
}

Comment: What else you expect it to return? `$.easyNotifier` is returning an instance. when u ll log it, it ll show code.

Comment: I think i moved a step further, 

Just put the console.log into a setTimeout function, and it returned an object, so if i am not getting this all wrong, even with all the public methods queued its still too fast too return the actual notifier object.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you are getting object in setTimeout coz setTimeout runs at window level and it can find notifier object. But when u try to run normally, you dont get notifier and that is why its undefined.